# How to fix $setPristine error in Angular JS?

Tags: angularjs

I have function in Angular JS, thats resets HTML form:

```
$scope.resetForm = function (formName)
{
   $scope.formData = angular.copy(formEdit);
   $scope.formName.$setPristine();
}
```

HTML look like as:

```
<form name="educAddForm" novalidate>
<div ng-click="resetForm(educAddForm)">Click</div>
```

After click I get error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property '$setPristine' of undefined
```

Comment: change `$scope.formName.$setPristine()` to `formName.$setPristine()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$scope.resetForm = function (formName)
{
   $scope.formData = angular.copy(formEdit);
   formName.$setPristine();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

+1 to PSL's comment. Change

`$scope.formName.$setPristine()`

to

`formName.$setPristine()`

Remember, because formName is being passed in to the function, even if a scope variable is being passed in, you should refer to it as it's parameter name in the scope of the function.